# Why are files listed alphabetically, ignoring file name length in the terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line

Why are files listed alphabetically, ignoring file name length in the terminal?

Perhaps I shouldn't say "ignoring" file name length, but rather, why is there a difference in displaying files in the terminal vs. a GUI.

This is certainly a trivial question, but I've been a bit curious about this one for a while.

In the terminal, a vanilla `ls` command using the `-l` option (with no other sorting options specified) lists files in alphabetical order starting from the top line of the list moving down. Say I have a directory full of files created with the following:

`$ touch file1{1..16}`

`ls` in that same directory would display the following:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file1
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file10
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file11
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file12
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file13
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file14
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file15
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file16
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file2
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file3
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file4
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file5
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file6
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file7
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file8
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user  0 May 24 11:14 file9
```

My question is why does "file10" follow "file1" in this way in the terminal? When viewing files in a details or list view ordered by name or type in a GUI environment, those same files are listed as "file1", "file2", "file3", etc.

Lists of files in a GUI seem to prioritize alphabetical order by file name length, listing files from smallest length to largest. Is this correct? Is there a more technical reason for this? Is the `ls` command "going out of its way" to order files the way it does, or likewise with a GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default ordering for `ls` is alphabetical. In this scenario, digits are not numbers just characters. So `file1` is a shorter name than `file10`, but otherwise identical, and therefore comes before it in the list.

If you want natural versioned order you could try `ls -l --sort=version` (or `ls -lv`)

```
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima 0 May 24 18:50 file0
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima 0 May 24 18:50 file1
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima 0 May 24 18:50 file2
...
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima 0 May 24 18:50 file9
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima 0 May 24 18:50 file10
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima 0 May 24 18:50 file11
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima 0 May 24 18:50 file12
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima 0 May 24 18:50 file13
```

There are a number of other sorting options available in `ls`; see `man ls` for details.

Comment: "Lexicographic" rather than "alphabetic", but it's just words.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you. if I could work out how to add that without adding unnecessary complexity for potentially non-native English speakers I would. (Feel free to edit if you can see how.)

Comment: @roaima Ah, thank you! I see that files are listed in order by characters at the end of each string, up until the "next" character in alphabetical or numerical order. So files listed with a ton of 1's in their file name will continue until something like "file2" is displayed.

Comment: @allenv exactly, yes. But actually it's slightly more complicated than that; you'll come across references to _locale_ soon enough, which is the umbrella term that discusses how to sort non-English characters such as ø á and even Kanji. Some characters even have no sort order.