# What naming convention can I use to ensure that file names sort in a consistent order using ls?

Tags: linux, ls

I'm trying to come up with a naming convention for a set of files such that they always sort in a consistent order without requiring any special options, but I'm having a difficult time achieving this.

If I have the following file names: `A.jpg`, `A1.jpg`, `A-1.jpg`, `A_1.jpg`, when I run `ls` from the command line with no options (which the man page says will "Sort entries alphabetically") I get the following order:

```
A-1.jpg, A_1.jpg, A1.jpg, A.jpg
```

It's unclear to me how this is actually sorting, because "-", "_", and "1" have ASCII values of 45, 95, and 49 so assuming it's sorting everything before the extension this is not in the correct order.  Further, if it's including "." that is ASCII value 46 so the second character values would be 45, 95, 49, 46.

If there are no extension, e.g. `A`, `A1`, `A-1`, and `A_1` then `ls` returns this order:

```
A, A-1, A_1, A1
```

In this case the ASCII values of the second character are NULL, 45, 95, 48 which *also* doesn't seem to be in any order but also is not even in the same order as if the extension was missing.

On the other hand, if I look at the directory in the GNOME file manager, I get the following order:

```
A.jpg, A1.jpg, A-1.jpg, A_1.jpg
```

which is also the output I get from `ls -v` of which the man page says "natural sort of (version) numbers within text".  In this case it appears to sort with no numbers first, then plain numbers, then prefixes to the number in ASCII order.

I think if I could understand how `ls` is actually sorting entries "alphabetically" when there are non-alphabetic characters that would go a long way.  From my simple test it's obviously not ASCII value order either, which is what I would expect, and it's not even clear exactly how the dot and extension figure into the whole thing.  What is `ls` doing???

Update: I've put some filenames in the order they are displayed with `ls` along with ASCII values in hexadecimal below:

```
A       0x41
A-1     0x41 0x2D
A_1     0x41 0x5F
A1      0x41 0x31
A-1.jpg 0x41 0x2D 0x31 0x2E 0x6A 0x70 0x67
A_1.jpg 0x41 0x5F 0x31 0x2E 0x6A 0x70 0x67
A1.jpg  0x41 0x31 0x2E 0x6A 0x70 0x67
AB      0x41 0x42
AB.jpg  0x41 0x42 0x2E 0x6A 0x70 0x67
A.jpg   0x41 0x2E 0x6A 0x70 0x67
```

Update 2:
In response to the comments, the output of `type -a ls` is:

```
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /usr/bin/ls
ls is /bin/ls
```

LC_COLLATE is not set.

```
$ set | grep LC_COLLATE
$ echo $LC_COLLATE

$
```

Comment: I get a different order: `A-1.jpg  A.jpg    A1.jpg   A_1.jpg` which makes more sense. What implementation of `ls` are you using? What's value of `LC_COLLATE`?

Comment: ... and post output of `type -a ls`

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate, [Why does `ls` list the following files in seemingly different orders?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328185/100397)

Comment: Have you seen https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445821/why-are-files-listed-alphabetically-ignoring-file-name-length-in-the-terminal?rq=1

Comment: I'd use `A_001.jpg`, `A_002.jpg`, etc. Read `man seq` and `man bash` about the `printf` builtin.

Comment: @waltinator the problem is, most files *don't* have a sequence number. I need some way of coming up with a sequence number after the fact that doesn't get sorted before the original one.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I have updated the question to include this information.

Comment: Why not just make a ls alias

Comment: It's also locale-dependent. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation#Labeling_of_ordered_items

Comment: Can you explain what order would you actually expect from `ls`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk At a minimum I would expect "A.jpg" to come before A<anything>.jpg" as this would allow me to come up with a convention by which conflicting file names could have something appended to the name and still come after the older copy.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It seems if I set LC_COLLATE=POSIX I get the order I expect, although using `locale` or `localectl` seems to set it but only for root. (maybe I need to reboot first?)

Comment: @Michael: you may just an environment variable

Answer (score 1):

Given the uncertainty that you point out with ls and variable length/delimited filenames it probably makes sense to use a fixed width format with only alphanumeric characters. Depending on how many files you plan to have this could include fixed width fields for descriptive names as well as indices.

| name field (10 digits, 'x' extended) | index field (6 digits, '0' extended) | '.' | file extension (3 digits) |

e.g.

```
xxxsealion000001.jpg
xxxxxxxcat000001.jpg
xxxxxxxcat009000.jpg
```

I can't do much better than this without knowing more about the relative sizes of categories, but you can obviously adjust the format above to have more index space or more description space (or more of both by making the fixed width longer). To make longer words go last pad description with '0' ('_' worked for me too, but goes against the first part of my answer), to make sure longer words go first pad them with 'z'

Comment: The main issue with a fixed format is that there are a large number of existing files (> 100,000) which mostly do *not* have indexes.  However, in the case of an occasional name collision this index is needed.

Comment: I might have an somewhat unconventional / awesome solution then. I just tried this on my machine. Give normal alphanumeric names, and if you have an index do as follows: cat.jpg cat.jpg.1 cat.jpg.2 ...

Comment: I'll try that... hopefully nothing gets confused with the unconventional "extension"